# Twilio-php - how to get messages, filtered by parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, twilio

I'm using Twilio-PHP in a Symfony application, using the [Vresh Twilio Bundle](https://github.com/fridolin-koch/VreshTwilioBundle). I'm retrieving SMS messages from my account as follows:

```
$twilio = $this->container->get('twilio.api');
$messages   = $twilio->account->messages
```

This gets me a list of every message in the account. I'd like to be able to filter this at point of the API call, to only retrieve messages with a certain direction, or after a certain date.

In the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-in-php#search-previous-messages), there is an example using

```
$params = array('DateSent' => '2017-10-20');
$messages = $twilio->account->messages->read($params);
```

...but the `read()` method doesn't exist for me.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException]
Attempted to call an undefined method named "read" of class "Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages".
```

Can anyone advise how to retrieve messages from Twilio, and filter them by parameter at the point of the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Michael has pointed out, you are using version 4 of the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php). Ideally you could upgrade to version 5, but if you want to stick with the Vresh Twilio Bundle, then you are currently stuck on version 4.

You can filter messages using this version of the library though. The documentation lives on in GitHub too, so you can see [how to use the Messages resource with Twilio PHP 4](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/4.12.0/docs/usage/rest/messages.rst). To filter messages you need the `getIterator` method and you can use it like this:

```
foreach ($client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
   'DateSent>' => '2017-10-20',
)) as $message) {
    // use $message
}
```

You can't filter by direction though, [only `To`, `From` and `DateSent`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message#list-filters).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Filtering by date should be fine for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing documentation for not right version: you use `4.x` version in your project but view documentation for `5.x`.

At the page that you linked to you have example for `4.x` version:

```
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
$token = "your_auth_token"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Loop over the list of messages and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->account->messages as $message) {
    echo $message->body;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, so it looks like v4 of the API perhaps didn't have the ability to filter by parameters. I'll look for a workaround in my code.